# How to show overlay info view with two button more when i click a marker on google in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, overlay-view

I am trying to show a custom overlay view from the Google Maps through the Google Maps API for iOS. This overlay view content info of marker, and two my button. But I cannot find any references for this. My desired overlay view is as image with link below:

http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l515/dungnlh_khtn07/NguoiMoCay/overlayinfoview_zps8110b7ed.jpg

Please give me a guide for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of achieving this is to pass your GMSMapView a custom view for your info windows via the GMSMapViewDelegate's `mapView:markerInfoWindow:` method.

To accomplish this, set yourself up as the delegate for your GMSMapView instance, like so:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

Then return a custom UIView when requested:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(id<GMSMarker>)marker
{
    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return customView;
}
```

You can find a little more information by looking in the GMSMapView header, which states:

```
/**
 * Called when a marker is about to become selected, and provides an optional
 * custom info window to use for that marker if this method returns a UIView.
 * If you change this view after this method is called, those changes will not
 * necessarily be reflected in the rendered version.
 *
 * The returned UIView must not have bounds greater than 500 points on either
 * dimension.  As there is only one info window shown at any time, the returned
 * view may be reused between other info windows.
 *
 * @return The custom info window for the specified marker, or nil for default
 */
```

Comment: Doesn't work, per comments below.  Actually hook up a demo with buttons and check it..

Answer (score 5):

Possibly, as mentioned officially in documentation of Google Maps Android API, the below restriction regarding infowindows applies to Google Maps iOs SDK also :

Info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.

So bascially clicking on any part of the infowindow will trigger only "didTapWindowOfMarker"

Answer (score 2):

OK, but can someone please clarify how to get a UIButton on that UIView to respond to touches? Like two buttons in Dung Nguyen Le Hoang's attached picture. For example, if I add a button like this:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(id<GMSMarker>)marker
{
    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

    [customView addSubview:button];

    return customView;
}
```

and of course have buttonPressed

```
- (void)buttonPressed
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

it doesn't get called. If I added the button as a subview to self.mapView then it appears on mapView, not InfoWindow and, of course, is responsive to touches. I suppose it's due to some unset frames, but can't quite get it. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Afraid not as the SDK renders UIView as an overlay image and that can't be responsive. I've made another solution: In method

-(BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker


I add a view as subview representing my Info Window and remember marker's coordinate at a @property so that that UIView can be repositioned in didChangeCameraPosition if the user moves the view. That UIView is then dismissed from view in 


-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate

method which is fired when the user taps elsewhere on the map.

Comment: @VladimirKolbas's answer is right. I had solved the same problem.

Comment: @Dalinaum have you got solve? Please provide some code, will be the great help. thanks in Adv.

Comment: @HardikDarji It's already 5 years ago. I don't have any code for that anymore. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker

Answer (score 0):

You can show **AlertView** or **ActionSheet** with two buttons when the user tap on the **markerInfoContents**